# How to Validate Telegram Bot Hash with C#?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm currently processing the URL obtained after clicking the login button. This involves excluding the hash, sorting the parameters alphabetically, formatting them as key=value, and using \n as the separator.

I have used SHA256 to process my secret key and then encrypted my string with the processed secret key. However, when comparing it with the hash from my URL, they differ.

Where might I be going wrong?

Additionally, I have a couple of questions:

Do I need to decode the value of photo_url? Since the original format looks like `https%3A%2F%2Ft.me`.
Is it necessary to convert the string to lowercase before processing it?
Thank you.

```cs
        public IActionResult GetTelegram([FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string> queryParams)
        {
            if (!queryParams.TryGetValue("hash", out var hash) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(hash))
            {
                return BadRequest("Missing hash parameter");
            }
            queryParams.Remove("hash");
            
            if (queryParams.ContainsKey("photo_url"))
            {
                queryParams["photo_url"] = WebUtility.UrlDecode(queryParams["photo_url"]);
            }
            
            var dataCheckString = string.Join("\n", queryParams.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key)
                                                                .Select(kv => $"{kv.Key}={kv.Value}"));

            var secretKey = ShaHash("Bot_Token");

            var myHash = HashHmac(secretKey, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataCheckString));

            var myHashStr = string.Concat(myHash.Select(i => i.ToString("x2")));
            if (myHashStr == hash)
            {
                return Ok("success。");
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized("fail。");
            }
        }

        private static byte[] ShaHash(string value)
        {
            using (SHA256 hash = SHA256.Create())
            {
                return hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
            }
        }

        private static byte[] HashHmac(byte[] key, byte[] message)
        {
            using (var hash = new HMACSHA256(key))
            {
                return hash.ComputeHash(message);
            }
        }
```

I'm using parameters like these:

```json
{
  "id": "xxxxx",
  "first_name": "xxxxx",
  "username": "xxxxxx",
  "photo_url": "https%3A%2F%2Ft.me%xxxxxx.jpg",
  "auth_date": "xxxxx",
  "hash": "xxxxxxxxx"
}
```